# ps aux | grep php --- check for GET arguments

Tags: php, shell, process

I have a self-made "Process Manager" for my site, that simply parses the shell command
`ps aux | grep php`

This is useful to see if a php process is taking too much CPU or MEM. However, sometimes I see some php processes delaying some time to complete. The problem is that this doesn't tell me much:

`/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/process.php`

Because, a process may depend a lot of what GET arguments it receives.

So, my question is, **is it possible to know what GET arguments did a PHP process receive?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`proctitle`](http://pecl.php.net/package/proctitle) to change the name of the php process to include the GET query string, assuming that you are on a Linux or BSD system.

Comment: Thank you. I'll investigate a little about it, and accept your answer if it works to me. Will it affect any functionality of the PHP scripts or something else? Or, will it just add the GET query string and that's all?

Comment: @NunoPeralta You'd need to add code to your process.php and call the [`setproctitle()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setproctitle.php) and pass it your query string.

Comment: Oh yeah! That's exactly what I want! That may be useful even for other things. Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Only problem is GET parameters are passed onto your script only when called via your web server and not from the command line, in your case your only going to get ARGS.

You can always do a grep on :

```
$ ps -auwwwx | grep my_php_script
```

to see the ARGs in the command line scripts

Comment: I have some cronjobs, and I pass GET arguments in this way: "process.php arg1=5 foo=bar". However, using "ps auwwwx" is not showing me any GET argument passed to the php processes. The output is about the same as "ps aux". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if somebody needs answeer to this problem, i can send commands from apache server to ubuntu console, just:
add www-data user permissions in sudoers file.

> www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

and execute command from php file

```
$comand2=  shell_exec('sudo -S service cron restart 2>&1' );
echo "<pre> $comand2 $</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see details of your progress on linux console via ps you have to use [proctitle](https://pecl.php.net/package/proctitle) this pecl extension will give you

[setproctitle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setproctitle.php)() function.

extension is very old but still working even zts mode.

If you are using cli version you can use : [cli-set-process-title()](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.cli-set-process-title.php) this is native php function (version PHP5 >=)

So simple code that i use to track on linux :

```
<?
if ((PHP_SAPI === 'cli' OR defined('STDIN'))) {
    $tmp = $_SERVER["argv"];
    unset($tmp[0]);
    $text =  "/". implode('/',$tmp);
    @cli_set_process_title (urldecode($text));
} else {
    @setproctitle (urldecode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
}
?>
```

I just write this to top index.php on codeigniter.

For see processes uses most cpu and memory at linux :

```
ps o pid,stat,time,pcpu,pmem,cmd -C php --sort -pcpu
```

now you will able to see processes